# How to position the form that is in the centre at the top?

Tags: html, css

My intention is to put the `<form>` just a little bit under the `<nav>`, so I want to position it at the top. It is already in the center.
I want to make it responsive, so for example when I go into mobile mode then the form should be in the center, but also at the top, just under the `<nav>`. I have already tried several ways to do it, but none of them worked. Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2b2d2e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #46484a 0%, #2e2e30 100%);
}

nav i {
  color: #d35858;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #343131;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container form textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.container form {
  background: rgb(82, 81, 81);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2vw 4vw;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

form h3 {
  color: rgb(213, 118, 118);
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

form input,
form textarea {
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: #d9cece;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form button {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(221, 107, 107);
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

form button:hover {
  background: rgb(236, 240, 239);
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.nav-link {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(42, 43, 43);
  left: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: -100px;
}

a:hover,
a.active {
  transition: .5s;
  color: rgb(239, 122, 122);
}

.nav-link ul li {
  padding: 18px;
}

.nav-link ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: -50vh;
}

.nav-bar-top ul {
  padding-top: 32px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a {
  color: #d5c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a.active {
  color: #fa9e9e;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a:hover {
  color: #d35858;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  #nav-bar-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-bar-top ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f2665b7baf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <label id="nav-bar-icon">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
    <div class="nav-bar-top">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="nav-link">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/c2dd7f214ec3e502a5410ae72d612526" method="POST">
      <h3>Contact us! </h3>
      <!--                 hint for the content of input /  required to give input-->
      <input class="input_text" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <br>
      <input class="input_text" type="email" name="email" tabindex="2" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <br>
      <textarea class="input_text" name="message" tabindex="3" placeholder="Your question" required></textarea>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/thanks.html">


    </form>


  </div>
  <script src="../js/index.js"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `container` class, change the following CSS styles:

```
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

to

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

And it should work.

From your description, I assume that you don't want the form to stretch to the bottom of the screen, so remove `height: 100vh` from this `container` and, for example, apply your background color to the `body`:

```
body {
  background: #343131;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #343131;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2b2d2e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #46484a 0%, #2e2e30 100%);
}

nav i {
  color: #d35858;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #343131;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container form textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.container form {
  background: rgb(82, 81, 81);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2vw 4vw;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

form h3 {
  color: rgb(213, 118, 118);
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

form input,
form textarea {
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: #d9cece;
  font-size: 16px;
}

form button {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(221, 107, 107);
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

form button:hover {
  background: rgb(236, 240, 239);
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.nav-link {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(42, 43, 43);
  left: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: -100px;
}

a:hover,
a.active {
  transition: .5s;
  color: rgb(239, 122, 122);
}

.nav-link ul li {
  padding: 18px;
}

.nav-link ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: -50vh;
}

.nav-bar-top ul {
  padding-top: 32px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a {
  color: #d5c9c9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a.active {
  color: #fa9e9e;
}

.nav-bar-top ul li a:hover {
  color: #d35858;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  #nav-bar-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .nav-bar-top ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f2665b7baf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <label id="nav-bar-icon">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
    <div class="nav-bar-top">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="nav-link">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/c2dd7f214ec3e502a5410ae72d612526" method="POST">
      <h3>Contact us! </h3>
      <!--                 hint for the content of input /  required to give input-->
      <input class="input_text" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <br>
      <input class="input_text" type="email" name="email" tabindex="2" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <br>
      <textarea class="input_text" name="message" tabindex="3" placeholder="Your question" required></textarea>
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/thanks.html">


    </form>


  </div>
  <script src="../js/index.js"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the container class in css, omit the 100vh height, because that's what makes the shape will be the center position of the screen because the 100vh height is to make the height match the screen height on the pc